# How to fix: API call to gmail.users.settings.filters.create failed with error: Empty response

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I wrote a script in google apps scripts that creates two filters. I implemented it into web app and it works fine on couple of accounts that aren't that big. But when i try to use it on main account, where it supposed to work I am getting an error that can't really understand.

> 'API call to gmail.users.settings.filters.create failed with error: Empty response (vers 69, file„createFilter”)'

```
function createFitler(labelold,me){
  var response = Gmail.Users.Labels.list('me');
  var labelID = "";
  var labelName = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < response.labels.length; i++) {    
    var label = response.labels[i];
    if(label.name == labelold)
    {
      labelID = label.id;
      labelName = label.name;
    } 
  } 

  var filter = Gmail.newFilter();
  var filter2 = Gmail.newFilter();

 filter.criteria = Gmail.newFilterCriteria();
  filter.criteria.from = labelold;  

  filter2.criteria = Gmail.newFilterCriteria();
  filter2.criteria.to = labelold;  


  filter.action = Gmail.newFilterAction();
  filter.action.removeLabelIds = ['INBOX'];
  filter.action.addLabelIds = [labelID];

  filter2.action = Gmail.newFilterAction();
  filter2.action.removeLabelIds = ['INBOX'];
  filter2.action.addLabelIds = [labelID];

  // Create the filter
  Gmail.Users.Settings.Filters.create(filter, me);
  Gmail.Users.Settings.Filters.create(filter2, me);

}
```

The weirdest part is that it works normal on my domain account but not on archive@mydomain.com account.

Comment: When you run it from the account where it does not work, did you share the script with that account? and if so, did you activate Advanced Gmail Services on both? filter management needs the service to be activated, do you know how to check if it is? Lastly, did you follow [this](http://www.jessespevack.com/blog/2018/9/6/how-to-create-a-gmail-filter-with-google-apps-script) tutorial?

Comment: I granted permisions, I shared the script, yes I activeted ADS on both. The weird part is that I didn't do it on MY FRIEND domain account and script worked perfectly

Comment: I notice that on the `Gmail.Users.Settings.Filters.create(filter, me);` you have `me` instead of `"me"` What are you passing to the `me` parameter of the function? Also, could you try creating a new script from your main account, and copy/pasting the code to see if it runs then?

Comment: `me` parametr is getting from another function. It is basilicaty this `var me = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();`
 I did try to use it from this account but still getting an error: 
`API call to gmail.users.settings.filters.create failed with error: Empty response (vers72, file „createFilter”)`

Comment: I am searching google and I found that it might be too big request for gmail API. This email acccount has 3500 Labels, couple tousends filters and it has 2,5TB. Now I see taht even with this code `Logger.log(Gmail.Users.Settings.Filters.list("me"));` I am getting "Empty Respnse"

Comment: Yes, the request might be too big and that's why it gives an empty response, I would suggest to try to follow [these guidelines](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1409688?hl=en), they display Google's best practice targets.